# How to add 2 mailboxes from 2 exchange servers each to one outlook 2016 profile?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, exchange, mailbox

I do have multiple accounts on two Exchange Servers.
Previous versions of Outlook allowed me to add these mailboxes independly (although it was never supported, it generally worked just fine). Outlook 2016 seems incapable to do so. The supported way is to used "additional mailboxes", but that is again only supported for the primary account. So I can have multiple mailboxes from one server but only one from the other.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: I am using Outlook 2016 and configured 2 exchange accounts from two different servers on different domain. Per my knowledge, since office 2007, outlook is supporting 3 exchange accounts. Are you getting any error while adding new account?

Comment: Microsoft Outlook 2010, Microsoft Outlook 2013, and Microsoft Outlook 2016 let you add multiple Microsoft Exchange accounts to the same profile. Do you have any group policy restricting this?

Comment: @Sandeep I have two mailboxes on each server. That's the problem.

Comment: @SteveFan This is about adding multiple mailboxes on the same server. That does not work on Outlook 2016. (And it was never supported.)

Comment: @SteffenHeil If the mailboxes are on the same server, it's not supported. This <https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/981245/issues-that-can-occur-when-you-add-multiple-exchange-accounts-in-the-s> Microsoft KB article said it's still possible in Outlook 2016 but not supported. I haven't tested it.

Comment: @SteveFan I know it's not supported and never was. But it worked fine with previous versions and I am just searching for a way to configure it in the new version. (Previous Outlook 2016 builds also allowed the configuration, but the current one does not.)

Comment: @SteffenHeil What isn't supported? Connecting several mailboxes as a separate Outlook accounts? It's fully supported. I personally have an Outlook 2016 profile with: 4 mailboxes from first Exchange, 2 mailboxes from second Exchange and 1 mailbox from third Exchange (outlook.com). Everything works flawless. Why can't you add your mailboxes? Error or what?